# Google Sheet update data from my server

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I create a Google Sheet add-on but now I need to update the sheet when there is new update on my server. I found there are 2 options.

1. use installable trigger to periodically pull values from my server.
2. use form submit trigger. I'm not sure whether this can be used for pulling data.

Which is the best option to pull data and update to Google Sheet for a published add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google just released Cloud Messaging Pub/Sub. This is a tool that covers exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/overview

Pub/Sub is an API that is designed for application to application messaging. You need to set up your script as a push webhook endpoint. It isn't obvious, nor documented, but I figured it out through exploration. This is needed to set up you add-ons and server for push notifications instead of using pulling.

1. Publish your script as a webapp.
2. Deploy it to the Chrome Store. You do not need to publish so you can leave it in draft.
3. Get the published WebApp URL.  It will look something like:

   ```
   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7STHODJlW...EjvowTaO0mmZ3TA9Xsdq1/exec
   ```
4. Go back the the Developer Console from your script and choose Push under API & Auth.
5. Add the domain specific URL  without the trailing 'exec' in my case :

   ```
   https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx7STHODJlW...EjvowTaO0mmZ3TA9Xsdq1/
   ```

Comment: @spencer-easton My app is already an add-on for Google Sheets. Can I republish as web app? I don't get it.

Answer (score 0):

The form submit trigger only happens when someone submits a Google Form.  I have no idea when and by what event your server is being updated.

If your server can submit an HTTP Request, you could use a Google Sheets API.

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/

The installable time trigger would be a lot easier.

Comment: Do you mean installable time trigger is easier than http request from my server?

Comment: Well, I really don't know how easy or hard the http request from your server would be.  Creating the trigger is easy.  Most people would find it easier to use a Google Apps Script with the SpreadsheetApp service rather than Google Sheets API.  So, yah.  The trigger is probably easier.